# String to hexadecimal

Tags: java, string, format, ip, hex

I need a method to convert a string "IP:PORT" into a byte array. I know how to format manually, but I need a way to do it automatically.

Example IP:

> 77.125.65.201:8099

I just can't use "".getBytes(); because I need the following format (without dot and colon):

> [#1 octet ip] [#2 octet ip] [#3 octet ip] [#4 octet ip] [#1 2 octet port]

For a better understanding:

> 77 125 65 201 8099

In Java manually I can set it:

```
byte[] testIP = { 0x4D, 0x7D, 0x41, (byte)0xC9, (byte)0x1FA3 };
```

I need to find a method that will return a byte array in the correct format, casting to byte when it's necessary (because of Java signed bytes).

This is what have I made but it's not working:

```
private void parseIp(String fullData){
   String[] data = fullData.split(":"); // 8099
   String[] ip = data[0].split("\\."); // 77 | 125 | 65 | 201

   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      System.out.println("---> " + toHex(ip[i]));
   }
}

private String toHex(String data){
   return Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(data, 16));
}
```

Comment: A Java byte can store -128 to 127. If we interpret them unsigned, we can store 0 to 255. There is no way to store 8099 in a single byte.

Comment: In your original string is `77` decimal or hexadecimal value?

Comment: When you say that your code "*is not working*", what does it actually mean? Are you getting any errors?  Are you not getting the expected result?  Please add all the details into your post.

Answer (score 4):

There is a special package in Java ti deal with internet addresses java.net, use it.

```
    String s = "77.125.65.201:8099";
    String[] a = s.split(":");
    InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName(a[0]);
    byte[] bytes = ia.getAddress();
    int port = Integer.parseInt(a[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private String parseAddressToHex(String address) {

    int result = 0;
    String[] str = address.split("\\.");
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        int j = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
        result = result << 8 | (j & 0xFF);
    }
    return Integer.toHexString(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your function toHex with this one.

```
private String toHex(String data){
   return Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(data));
}
```

Comment: the only problem with this is that it converts a '1' to '1' and not '01'

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that is causing you problems here is that convert to bytes, you *actually* DON'T need to use "hex" at all.  All you really need to do is convert 1-3 digit decimal numbers to bytes, and a 1-5 digit decimal number to a pair of bytes: e.g.

```
private byte[] parseIp(String fullData){
   String[] data = fullData.split(":"); 
   String[] ip = data[0].split("\\."); 
   byte[] res = new byte[6];

   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      res[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(ip[i]);
   }
   port = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
   res[4] = (byte)((port >> 8) & 0xff);
   res[5] = (byte)(port & 0xff);
   return res;
}
```

(The above needs some error checking ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code that i copied from: [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                             + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your code works like charm for me, after making the compiler happy (java se7u21-x64 on win7). here comes the standalone .java file:

```
//
//  27.04.2013 16:26:32
//

public class  ipconvert {
    private static void parseIp(String fullData){
       String[] data = fullData.split(":"); // 8099
       String[] ip = data[0].split("\\."); // 77 | 125 | 65 | 201

       System.out.println();
       System.out.print("---> " + toHex(ip[0]));
       for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++){
          System.out.print("."+toHex(ip[i]));
       }
       System.out.println(":"+data[1]);
    }

    private static String toHex(String data){
       return Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(data, 16));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String stest;

        System.out.println("SO tests");
        System.out.println();
        stest = new String("77.125.65.201:8099");
        parseIp ( stest );
        System.out.println();
        return;
    }
}
```